# Redefining environment within a macro

Tags: macros, environments

Hel-lo, I am a LaTeX programming newbie.

While formatting my document, I found that it will look nice if I can modify the theorem environment (with *amsthm* package). So I tried the following code

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\@envcount
\newcommand{\enclosebox}[2]{%
    % Create copies of old environments
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\@old\csname #1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\@oldend\csname end#1\endcsname%
    % Redefine environment using old ones.
    \renewenvironment{#1}[1][]{%
        \@nameuse{@old}[##1]%
        \begin{#2}%
    }{%
        \end{#2}%
        \@nameuse{@oldend}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

This command inserts a new environment (with name #2) to the original environment (with name #1). With this, I can modify theorem environments like this:

```
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \enclosebox{theorem}{<some box environment>}
```

The problem is, the token `\@old` and `\@oldend` are overwritten whenever I call `\enclosebox` command. For example,

```
 \enclosebox{theorem}{shadebox}
 \enclosebox{definition}{shadebox}
 \enclosebox{example}{leftbar}
```

overwrites my old definition and theorem environment, resulting in something like:

> [image]

So I tried using `\csname ~ \endcsname` to assign the name dynamically, but the compiler just spits out a bunch of errors.

Of course I can resolve this problem by pasting multiple copy of the code and modifying each one by hands... but I am doing in this way just to avoid this clumsy solution.

I have no idea how to fix my code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### For a solution with the original `framed` package, see below

As an ready to use alternative, instead of using `framed` and doing all the work, I'd suggest you to use `\surroundwithmdframed` from the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) that was designed specifically for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\surroundwithmdframed[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=gray!30]{theorem}
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=red,backgroundcolor=cyan!30]{definition}
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=red,backgroundcolor=orange!30,roundcorner=10pt]{example}

\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[4]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a possibility using `framed` and the `etoolbox` package to easily define your command `\enclosebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!30}

\newcommand\enclosebox[2]{%
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{#1}{\begin{#2}}%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{#1}{\end{#2}}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\enclosebox{theorem}{framed}
\enclosebox{example}{shaded}
\enclosebox{definition}{leftbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[4]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggesting such a nice package. It does fit into my problem. Actually, however, I also want to learn something new LaTeX programming skills so that eventually I can resolve other similar problems by my hand. If you don't mind, would you help me also in this way? (Or maybe I can look through the source code of *that* package...)

Comment: @sos440 I added another approach to my answer; this time using `framed` and defining your command, with the help of the `etoolbox` package. If you want to, I could also add a manual solution, but I'm tired now, so it will be in some hours :-)

Comment: @sos440 -- the recommendation to use `mdframed` is a good one.  an attempt by the maintainers of `amsthm` to provide a facility like the one you ask for ended with a result in which equation numbers on the right extended outside the frame area. with the availability of `mdframed`, the attempt to provide a `native` solution were abandoned.